# Programmatically schedule C# code

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on a simple framework were users can schedule some SQL queries to run at ***x*** time, every ***y*** days.

1. users can add through a website two parameters: **SQL Query** and **the
   time and day when it will run**. These parameters are stored in a SQL
   table
2. I have a C# program that will run the stored SQL query and send the
   results on an email.

Just need to know how to program in C# an scheduler that based on these parameters stored in the db, can run my C# code.

Windows Task Scheduler or Third party software are not allowed by the systems limitations

Comment: Please give us some sample schedule data (in C# code) and show us the code that will execute query and email the results.

Comment: you can schedule a job in sql server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the system scheduler (Windows Scheduler / crontab) to execute your C# code on the expected schedule. Then your C# program can simply take care of connecting to the DB, getting the queries and running them.

You might also want to consider adding a small bit of security into this, even something as simple as a salted hash that you verify before executing the query. Just in case someone figures out a way to add some unauthorized records into your table...

Comment: I think an always up service would be option because the time the job needs to be run can be dynamic

Comment: hi mate.. Needs to be done through C#.. windows scheduler is not allowed

Comment: In that case, Ipsit's comment would be best - a service. Just be aware that you have to consider the things that could possibly go wrong over time as the program is running (e.g. the database server restarts, your service crashes, etc...). Once you have the basic barebones service, use a Timer and evaluate the current DateTime to see if it falls on the expected schedule.

Comment: [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) in a Windows Service can be a solution. You can schedule jobs to run based on a [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) expression.
[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) can be a solution too but I have never tested it.